# Is it possible to transfer TortoiseSVN (on Windows7) to TortoiseHG (on Linux)?

Tags: git, mercurial, tortoisesvn, tortoisehg, tortoisegit

If I have two boxes both with Windows OS, that's no problem for me.

However, suppose I have different OS platforms: I currently use TortoiseSVN on my Windows 7 box, but I'll switch to using Ubuntu now. I want my existing TortoiseSVN log to work on my Ubuntu box. Is it possible for me to transfer the log from TortoiseSVN (on Windows) to TortoiseHG (on Linux)?

To recap:

- I have: TortoiseSVN on Windows 7
- Moving to: TortoiseHG* on Ubuntu

* Or is there Tortoise + Git available?

Comment: This may help: http://digitalseeds.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/migrating-from-tortoisesvn-to-tortoisehg/

Comment: Also, https://groups.google.com/d/topic/tortoisesvn/RRZCBmhKSW8/discussion

Comment: Based on those I'd do it s 2 parts, SVN to HG, then windows to Ubuntu (which should just be a file copy at that point).  Alternately, Copy from Windows to Ubuntu first, then SVN to HG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. Handle the two transfers seperately though:

1. *Migrating your SVN repository to Hg (or Git).* There are plenty of tutorials out there about this, allowing you to keep your history/log.
2. *"Migrating" your repo from box Windows to Linux.* For Hg this is just a matter of moving your repository folder with all its contents, I suspect for Git this is the same. For SVN I'm not entirely sure, but you could always just do a fresh checkout on your Linux box.

As for your second question, I don't think TortoiseGit is available for Linux. There are other [Git GUI clients for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux) though.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: In case of Subversion as CVCS you **must** also remember about **repositories**, which you use by TortoiseSVN (which is only client to central part of Subversion): they can be remote (http:// or svn:// accessible) or local (over File:/// RA-layer). Why it is important for you? After migration to new OS and new SCM you have to save access to SVN-repo for at least one action: conversion SVN-repo to Mercurial repository and it can be problematic in case of local repository on NTFS-disc (or|and on unmountable partition).

Given the above condition, your migration path can be

- Install new client for new SCM on new OS
- Add bridge to Subversion into your DVCS (both Git and Mercurial have it)
- Convert Subversion repo to DVCS repo
- Use new DVCS and forget Subversion